# How do I open a security van in GTA V?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

It's early days yet but in the spirit of open world one of the first things I've done in GTA V is hijack a security van. For the life of me I can't work out how to get the cash out of it.

I've tried a shotgun on the doors (the free bullshot one from the Special Edition), kicking, punching and machine gunning. I've also tried pretty much every button on the controller just in case it's something simple but so far my truck is impenetrable.

I'm currently left wondering if I'm just too early in the game to be able to open the security trucks although it was highlighted by the game as a "world event" (?) which would suggest not.

I would just save it for later but you can't store these vehicles in garages and I'd hate to just leave a truck full of money on the side of the road.

Can anyone shed light on how to get into these things?

Edit: Other things I've now tried:

- Reversing into buildings at high(ish) speed.
- Driving off the big hill behind the Vinewood sign. Killed me but didn't appear to open the truck.
- Driving into the shallow lake at the north end of the storm drain. The truck was fully submerged and again didn't open.

For reference my most recent story mission is no.3 "Repossession".

Comment: Why no one's reading the instructions on the left when it appears... It clearly says that you have to shoot between the doors handle to open it... dang

Comment: @Warface Because I stole the van very early in the game I didn't get the prompt saying how to open the doors and shooting them didn't work (as I mentioned). It turned out the only way I could open that particular van was to blow it up. A couple of missions later and I could shoot the doors, then about 4 vans later the game finally game me the "shoot the doors in the middle" prompt.

Comment: I can't answer just yet on this site but here's what I done before I had sticky bombs: Pull up the truck next to a propane tank and keep shooting that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I went to Lago Zancudo, there is a gas station where I fortunately found a tanker (what trucks use to carry gas). I parked the security van next to it and I shot the tanker from a distance. Four shots later it blew up and open the backdoor, dropping a brief case with $7,000!!!!

Comment: Good call. You don't need the tanker though, just pull up next to one of the fuel pumps and shoot that. From a safe distance of course.

Comment: This answer gets the "answered" flag as where I was in the game guns didn't work and sticky bombs weren't yet available. Natural explosives (gas tanks, tankers or cars) were the only things that worked. Since then stickies, shotguns and all the others answers have worked just fine. +1 to all of them :-)

Comment: @PeteWiFi This comment is really nice because it describes why it was accepted over the other, better answers. Not many people leave comments like this one.

Answer (score 13):

Once you unlock sticky bombs you can apply one to the back of the van and blow it. It will open the doors without destroying the contents. It is the easiest and most efficient method.

Comment: This isn't by any mean the most easy and efficient way. In fact, it's one of the most expensive way. Just shooting right in the middle of the back door will do the trick.

Answer (score 10):

It's very simple, take out your shotgun and fire in between the two back doors. After 4 or 5 shots, the doors will pop open and a briefcase will drop to the ground. I have been getting different amounts, last time it was $20,000 in it then if you have the cops after you lose them.

Comment: Couldn't get this to work for me early on with the Bullshot shotgun. A little further into the game (mission 11) and this worked like a charm with the pump action.

Comment: @PeterFinney You probably needed a few more shots. I remember I had to open a van, but we were both driving and I only had a pistol. I had to shoot several dozens of rounds until the van's door opened.

Comment: Tried 60+ shots with the bullshot. I was parked outside an Ammunation so when it didn't pop with the first few I stocked up and painted the door black. Only had 7 shells and a pump action the second time I found a van and it popped right open. Odd, but hey we now have a nice selection of methods on here that all work. Difficulty is going to be picking the chosen answer.

Comment: You can also you a sticky bomb. Very fast and effective.

Answer (score 7):

Shoot the doors right in the middle where they meet. it'll take a while, but it works.

Comment: Takes about 4-6 shots for me with the basic shotgun.

Answer (score 7):

What I did was carjack a random car, park it right up against the back of the truck, and just shoot it till it explodes. I got like $7500!!

Answer (score 1):

I always just throw a sticky explosive onto the backdoor. It's worked first time every time for me.

Answer (score 0):

Shoot it a couple of times with a pistol that did it for me

Comment: I emptied my magazine into it and nothing. Start of the game, so basic pistol and only a couple of hundred shots.