# How can I open this armored vehicle in GTA-V?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

Michael was driving around flat-broke when he passed his first armored truck, so he shot out the tires and the driver, then jacked the truck and took off with rims ablaze.  After a near never-ending two star chase the truck is his, but he only has small arms and can't afford any grenades (stronger munitions are still level-locked).

So how could one break open an armored truck without adequate explosives?

[image: The treasure!]

There's the truck.  Michael is actually in the driver's seat, the shootout in the back is completely unrelated.

Answer (score 5):

Ways to open the doors:

- Use a sticky bomb
- Shoot in the middle of both doors with a shotgun(best chance with a pump action)
- Park a car behind the truck and blow up the car.

Stealing a police car usually adds a shotgun to your weapons inventory.

Comment: Shotgun worked for me. Popped right open.

Answer (score 4):

After you can see the engine without protection by crashing the truck, shoot the engine till explosion.

And maybe you can check on this: [How do I open a security van in GTA V?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/131181/how-do-i-open-a-security-van-in-gta-v?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

Go to the beach and find a small bonfire. Park the truck over the fire, walk away as it burns and explodes then you are golden.

Answer (score 0):

Blow up the engine, or like other people have said, use the shot gun to open the back doors, note, using the shot gun takes a while, but if you just blow up the car, the money goes every where & the cops are called. Just note they both work but they both have flaws

Answer (score 0):

light the truck on fire with a jerry can(found at certain gas station). When it explodes, the briefcase will just poped out of the truck. 2 stars will appear. :)